# how to run a function which calling in Handler after this function completly executed

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i want my SyncMessageFromServer() execute after delay of 5000 when SyncMessageFromServer() executed successfully;

my function is as below

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SyncMessageFromServer();
            }
        }, timer);

private void SyncMessageFromServer() {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FromServer Run", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(isInternetOn() && loginUserInfoId != "") {
            String str = "";
            HttpResponse response;
            HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.2/AndroidApp/GetAllMessage/" + loginUserInfoId);

            try {
                response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
                str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
                for (int i = 0; i <= jArray.length() - 1; i++) {
                    JSONObject row = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (row.getString("SenderUserId") != loginUserInfoId) {
                        ChatMessage cm = new ChatMessage();
                        String onlineFileURL = "";
                        String fileType = "";
                        String upFileURL = row.getString("FileAttachedURL").replace(" ", "%20");
                        String offlineFileURL = "";
                        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

                        if (upFileURL.contains(".mp4")) {
                            fileType = "VIDEO";
                            otherFileName = "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4";
                            onlineFileURL = "http://192.168.1.2" + row.getString("FileAttachedURL").replace("OutputVideo/", "");
                            timer = 60000;
                            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(onlineFileURL);

                            offlineFileURL = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/Planetskool/Media/Videos/" + otherFileName;
                        }

                        else {
                            fileType = "";
                            offlineFileURL = "";
                            timer = 3000;
                        }

                        /******* Firstly take data in model object ******/
                        cm.setOriginalMsgThreadId(row.getString("MessageThreadId"));
                        cm.setSenderUserInfoId(row.getString("SenderUserId"));
                        cm.setReceiverUserInfoId(row.getString("MultipleReceiversId"));
                        cm.setMessageStatus("SENT");
                        cm.setIsPending(0);
                        cm.setIsPendingToUpdate(1);
                        cm.setMessageText(row.getString("MessageText"));
                        cm.setMediaURL(offlineFileURL);
                        cm.setThumbImage(offlineFileURL);
                        cm.setMediaMIMEType(fileType);
                        cm.setMediaSize(0);
                        cm.setMediaName("");
                        cm.setLatitude("");
                        cm.setLongitude("");
                        cm.setSendTimeStamp(row.getString("SendTime"));
                        cm.setReceiveTimeStamp(timeStamp);


                        long messageId = db.SendMessage(cm);
                        //Log.d("MyService", "ChatMessageId = " + messageId);
                        Intent iMla = new Intent("REFRESH_DATA");
                        iMla.putExtra("id", messageId);
                        //intent.putExtra("id", messageId);
                        sendBroadcast(iMla);


                        String notiAvatarURL = "";
                        String notiUserName = "";
                        List<ChatMessageThread> allChatMessageThread = db.GetMessageThreadsById(row.getString("SenderUserId"));
                        for (ChatMessageThread chatMessageThread : allChatMessageThread) {

                            notiAvatarURL = chatMessageThread.getMessageThreadAvatarURL();
                            notiUserName = chatMessageThread.getMessageThreadTitle();

                        }
                        if (row.getString("SenderUserId") != loginUserInfoId) {
                            displayNotificationMessage(row.getString("MessageText"), notiAvatarURL, notiUserName);
                        }
                        confirmSyncedToServer(row.getString("MessageId"));
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SyncMessageFromServer();
                //SyncPendingMessageToServer();
            }
        }, timer);
    }
```

i want this function regularly executed after completed execution if i am giving it the delay of 5000 milisecond then it dsn't download my videos completly it download only how much it can download in 5000 miliseconds

Answer (score -1):

Use in this manner to call to call your method every 5 second

```
public void scheduleEvery5Sec() {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                // call method here 
            SyncMessageFromServer();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```